# How can you determine the number of occurrences of a keyword in a web page?

Tags: php, string, html, find-occurrences

I'm trying to figure out how search for the number of occurrence for a keyword on a php webpage. Not a string but count the occurrences and then post the number, for how many times a certain number appears on the page. Are there any functions for this.

The only related function I see is "substr_count". Again I don't want to count the occurrences in a string but a whole page.

Comment: @Fonzworth don't forget check as correct ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string_to_search = 'whao';
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo  substr_count($page, $string_to_search);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is feed the html of the page into the function `substr_count` as a string and then count the occurrences in that string.